# mongoDB won't stop with shutdown or kill

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Not sure If I can make the same question already made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277428/mongodb-wont-stop-with-shutdown-or-kill) but here it goes.

I have a mongodb fork and running with high CPU usage. I'm trying to shut it down but nothing seems to work.

```
 2729 mwon      20   0 10.080g 9.047g  22668 S  56.2 28.8   4254:11 mongod --dbpath /disk2/db --port 27018 -logpath /disk2/db/mongod.log --fork
```

I have tried:

```
mongod --dbpath /disk2/db --shutdown
```

but it hangs without any kind of response. I also tried:

```
 kill 2729
 kill -2 2729
```

The command gets executed but nothing happens. This is the `tail` of the log:

```
2019-07-30T15:55:27.757+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13356] end connection 127.0.0.1:45690 (62 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.758+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13368] end connection 127.0.0.1:45764 (61 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.759+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13380] end connection 127.0.0.1:45826 (60 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.764+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13381] end connection 127.0.0.1:45832 (59 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.764+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13369] end connection 127.0.0.1:45772 (58 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:55:27.765+0000 I NETWORK  [conn13344] end connection 127.0.0.1:45628 (57 connections now open)
2019-07-30T15:59:17.043+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2019-07-30T15:59:17.044+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-07-30T15:59:17.044+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27018.sock
2019-07-30T16:23:37.773+0000 I NETWORK  [conn11035] end connection 127.0.0.1:48928 (56 connections now open)
```

Comment: You can try with `kill -15 2729` (15 is TERM (software termination signal)). If that doesn't succeed, then `kill -9 2729` surely will ;) (9 is KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)) Oh, the default is 15 which you already tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands:

```
kill <process id> 
kill -2 <process id> 
kill -SIGHUP <process id>
kill -SIGQUIT <process id> 
kill -SIGTERM <process id> 
kill -SIGKILL <process id>
```

or

1. Log on to your database
2. Switch to admin database
3. Execute the command db.shutdownServer() to gracefully shutdown mongodb which is the safest way to shut down the DB

Thank you!

-Anban